# How do I draw the following triangles in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw in tikz the following image:

[image]

I am not sure where to start. I thought of maybe having a node which is of triangle shape, and then positioning it in different places.

I started with this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[fill=white,shape=circle,draw=black, minimum size=4cm] (A) at (0,4.3) {A};
\node[fill=white,shape=circle,draw=black, minimum size=3cm] (A) at (0,3.2) {A};
\node[fill=white,shape=circle,draw=black, minimum size=2cm] (A) at (0,2.1) {A};
\node[fill=white,shape=circle,draw=black, minimum size=1cm] (A) at (0,1.1) {A};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There are several things:

1. I thought of changing the circle shapes to triangles, but when I put "triangle" instead of "circle" it doesn't work -- even though I use the shapes library.
2. I want the letter A to appear above the shape, not in the middle.
3. I want a squiggly line to connect the top of all shapes. Any squiggly line would do fine.

Answer (score 4):

I would define a triangle "node" using a `pic` (see section 18.2 of the tikz manual, version 3.0.1a). For the MWE, we need to specify the height of the triangle and the label, so the `pic` needs to accept two arguments. One way to do this is to define a "triangle" `pic` as:

```
\tikzset{
  pics/triangle/.style args ={#1,#2}{% pic=triangle{label, height}
        code = {
          \draw(0,0)node[left]{$#1$} -- ++(#2/2,-#2) -- ++(-#2,0) -- cycle;
        }
     }
}
```

This is just "normal" `tikz` code that gets placed whenever you "call" the `pic`. So, for example, with this in place you could draw a triangle of height `3` and label `S` with:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,3) {triangle={S,3}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

There are several other ways to "draw" `pics`. For example, you can also draw this triangle with `\draw(0,3)pic{triangle={S,3}};`.

The easiest way to draw your "squiggly lines" is probably using a "snake decoration" -- see section 48.3 of the manual.

Putting this all together you can produce the diagram

[image]

using the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  triangle/.style = {draw=black, fill=brown!5, thick},
  squiggle/.style = {decoration={snake, segment length=5mm}, decorate},
  pics/triangle/.style args ={#1,#2}{% pic=triangle{label, height}
        code = {
          \draw[triangle] (0,0)node[left]{$#1$} -- ++(#2/2,-#2) -- ++(-#2,0) -- cycle;
        }
     }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,3) {triangle={S,3}};
  \pic at (0,2) {triangle={P,2}};
  \pic at (0,1) {triangle={P,1}};

  \draw[squiggle](0,2) -- (0,3);
  \draw[squiggle](0,1) -- (0,2);

  \draw[-{Latex[open]}] (2,1.5) -- ++(2,0);% using arrows.meta

  \pic at (6,3) {triangle={S,3}};
  \pic at (6,2) {triangle={P,2}};
  \pic at (6,1) {triangle={P,2}};
  \pic at (6,0) {triangle={P,2}};
  \pic at (6,-1.5) {triangle={P,0.5}};

  \foreach \bot/\y in {-1.5/1.5, 0/1, 1/1, 2/1} {
    \draw[squiggle](6,\bot) -- ++(0,\y);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Partly to show how to do it, and partly to fine-tune the diagram (particularly the `segment length` for the snake), I have added some styling.

Answer (score 1):

You called all the nodes `A`, which is probably not what you want, and you may use polygon instead of triangle. Putting a label on top of a node can be achieved by `label=above:`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} 

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw=black,
minimum size=4cm,label=above:A,anchor=south] (A1) at (0,4.3) {};
\node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw=black,
minimum size=3cm,label=above:A,anchor=south] (A2) at (0,3.2) [above]{};
\node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw=black,
minimum size=2cm,label=above:A,anchor=south] (A3) at (0,2.1) [above]{};
\node[fill=white,shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw=black,
minimum size=1cm,label=above:A,anchor=south] (A4) at (0,1.1) [above]{};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now you can play with the coordinates. If you are always drawing the same thing just with different scales, you may consider using `scope`.