# How do I add arguments in xparse?

Tags: xparse

I have this code (based on Andrew's answer at [How can I use rotate inside a defined TikZ command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409312/how-can-i-use-rotate-inside-a-defined-tikz-command/409527?noredirect=1#comment1022514_409527)).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\Triangle{ O{} r()}{% Syntax: [draw options] (lefthand endpoint
  \draw[#1] (#2) node{$\bullet$} -- ++(1,1.5) node{$\bullet$};
  \draw[#1] (#2) -- ++(2,0) node{$\bullet$};
  \draw[#1] ($(#2)+(1,1.5)$) -- ++(1,-1.5);
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Triangle[rotate=30](0,0);
        \Triangle[rotate=-10](2.5,0);
        \Triangle(5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to add three more arguments as names replacing the bullets at the vertices.  I have tried to follow the instructions on several blogs plus in the xparse documentation and i cannot get it to work.  I'm sure the right way is simple once you know it.  Can someone show it to me?

Comment: Assuming that they are mandatory arguments, `\NewDocumentCommand\Triangle{ O{} r() m m m }{....macro code...}`. (The space between the letters is for clarity only, it is not required.) Then you would have `#1`, `#2`, ..., `#5` at your disposal in the macro code.

Comment: If you only have one optional argument at the beginning, \newcommand can handle that.

Comment: @JohnKormylo But it can't handle the `()` delimited first argument.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Ah, I was wondering what that was for.

Comment: I'm not sure what is really going into your `\Triangle`-like macros but another approach is to define a [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) `pic`, as described in section 18.2 of the tikz manual. There are many examples of these on TeX.SX such as my post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408833/how-do-i-draw-the-following-triangles-in-latex/408838#408838, which defines a possibly related`pic` for drawing some triangles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand my comment: you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\Triangle{ O{} mmm r()}{
  % Syntax: [draw options]{node1}{node2}{node3}(lefthand endpoint)
  \draw[#1] (#5) node{$#2$} -- ++(1,1.5) node{$#3$};
  \draw[#1] (#5) -- ++(2,0) node{$#4$};
  \draw[#1] ($(#5)+(1,1.5)$) -- ++(1,-1.5);
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Triangle[rotate=30]{A}{B}{C}(0,0);
        \Triangle[rotate=-10]{D}{E}{F}(2.5,0);
        \Triangle{G}{H}{I}(5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

to produce:

[image]

The arguments to `\Triangle` are specified as `O{} mmm r()`. In order, these mean:

- `O{}` says that `#1` is an optional argument, that is given as `[#1]`, and which defaults to "nothing". This is used to give an optional argument to `\draw` via `\draw[#1]`
- `mmm` says that `#2`, `#3` and `#4` are mandatory arguments (this could also be specified as `m m m` etc)
- `r()` says that `#5` is a required/mandatory argument that must be given in the form `(#5)`